# jQuery SlideUp...But dont disappear off screen

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to use .slideUp, but the object only slideUp by (For instance) by 20px instead of disappearing off screen?

HTML:

```
<div class="toolbar">
  <p>Hide</p>
   <ul>
    <li>Tab 1</li>
    <li>Tab 2</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(".toolbar p").click(function() {
    $(".toolbar").slideUp(); 
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `animate` instead.

```
$('#myDiv').animate(
    {
        top: "-=20px"
    }, 300);
```

Slides your div up 20 pixels in 300 ms.